# Future Date applescript doesn't trigger

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm a freelancer, and wanted to set up an automator service so I could quickly insert the date 14 days from todays date to invoices.
The script runs fine within automator and produces the desired result, but I can't get it to actually trigger with the keyboard shortcut I assigned to it, or by activating the service through the application menu.

Any help would be appreciated in troubleshooting, or if there are better ways of achieving this I would gladly take them on board.

Right now this is my script

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "System Events"
        set _date to ((current date) + (days * 14))
        keystroke ¬
            text -2 thru -1 of ("00" & ((day of _date) as integer)) & "/" & ¬
            text -2 thru -1 of ("00" & ((month of _date) as integer)) & "/" & ¬
            (year of _date as text)
    end tell
end run
```

**Edit 2**

Thanks to @vadian and @RobC for your help in simplifying that code!
I have changed my keyboard shortcut to something I'm sure isn't being used but still no luck in getting any outcome mysteriously. Having a shortcut isn't necessary for me, providing I can get it working.
Attached are screenshots from Automator and the system preferences for Keyboard shortcuts, to see if I'm going wrong anywhere there?

[System Preferences Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpaOO.png)

[Automator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJck7.png)

Comment: You can create the date a bit simpler with `set datePlus14Days to do shell script "/bin/date -v+14d +%d%m%Y"`

Comment: @vadian - OP seems to want future date formatted as `DD/MM/YYYY`, if that's the requirement, your shell script should be `"/bin/date -v+14d +%d/%m/%Y"` (i.e. add the  `/` in the formatting)

Comment: @RobC Thanks, of course, I overlooked the slashes

Comment: @RobC, thanks for your help on simplifying that code! Ive updated my post with a couple of screenshots to hopefully shed some light on where i might be going wrong.

Comment: In case you're still doing so, don't run a `do shell script` command from inside an AppleScript action from insde Automator.  Better to have two separate actions: the first being a shell script, that leads into the AppleScript.  Alternatively, in this situation, you could do both from a single shell script, and use `osascript` to execute the AppleScript, which sounds equivalent to doing it he other way round, but it isn't.  You can (ought to) also move the `set _date to...` assignment to before the `tell` block, as calls a command (`current date`) that doesn't belong to System Events.

Comment: @CJK I have no idea why, but that last tip has solved my problem! Thanks!

Comment: Whenever you send an AppleScript command to an application that doesn't own that command, the script throws an error and often silently.  _Script Editor_ passes the command up the inheritance chain to `current application`, an instance of the application executing the script, into which `standard additions`  commands are loaded.  Running an AppleScript from inside _Automator_ is fine when _Automator_ the app is open; when you run it as a service, `current application` is service runner program that likely has the command kept in an `AppleScript` instance and not `current application`

Answer (score 1):

I had a couple of after-thoughts about your script, with some suggestions that aren't in any way critical but, in theory, might provide a small performance improvement and *maybe* additional stability.  For the sake of continuity, and benefit of others wanting to learn what fixed the initial problem, here's a summary of my earlier comments from above; skip to the section after for some additional suggestions:

#### Prelude

- <strike>It wasn't clear at the time which script you had adopted, but one of the variants makes a call to `do shell script` from inside a **Run AppleScript** action, from inside *Automator*, but it can be a performance drain on a slow system so you might get a more responsive workflow if you:</strike>

  1. Split the workflow into a **Run Shell Script** action to retrieve the date, then a **Run AppleScript** action to do the AppleScript bits; *OR*
  2. Do it all from a within a single **Run Shell Script** action, within which you can use `osascript` to execute the AppleScript.  It sounds equivalent to doing it he other way round, but it isn't.
- You should keep *Scripting Additions* commands separate from any commands belonging to an application that get sent within a `tell` block.  Specifically, move this line:

  ```
  set _date to ((current date) + (days * 14))
  ```

  to before (and, thus, outside) the `tell` block.  Requiring *System Events* to return the `current date`—a command it doesn't understand—-throws a (silent) error, and sends the command up the inheritance chain until it reaches the `current application` instance into which the *Scripting Additions* commands are loaded.  This consequently affects performance, but isn't surprising to have fixed the problem: the *Workflow Service Runner* isn't an application and likely doesn't have a `current application` instance of its own into which to load the additions commands (they'll still be accessible through the `AppleScript` instance itself, but only outwith any `tell application` block).

#### Additional Thoughts

The AppleScript can be improved/optimised by using a special class into which we can coerce a `date` object and have it return an ISO 8601-formatted date and time string, e.g. `"2019-06-20T09:41:45"`.  This is simpler and quicker to decompose into its date components and reassemble into a standard British-formatted date string.  Here's the code:

```
property text item delimiters : { "/", "-", "T"}

return text items 1 thru 3 of ¬
    ((current date) + 14 * days as ¬
    «class isot» as string) as text
```

**Aside:** Should you ever transition from British-formatted to ISO-8601 standard-formatted dates, e.g. `"2019-06-20"`, the AppleScript code simplifies and performs even more:

```
property text item delimiters : { "/", "-", "T"}

return text 1 thru 10 of ((current date) + ¬
    14 * days as «class isot» as string)
```

Currently, you're getting *System Events* to insert the date by effectively typing it out for you.  It's not a bad method, it's not a great method, but most importantly, it's overlooked an option that's right underneath your nose:

[image: Automator Service Workflow in macOS (AppleScript)]

Namely, the option *`Output replaces selected text`* built right into *Automator*.  I think it's easy to overlook because of the phrase "selected text", which one tends to think of as the visibly-highlighted selections that always include at least one character.  But, to use the AppleScript nomenclature for the class name, a `selection-object` in a text input always exists, and the value of the selected text is, at the very least, `""`.  Basically, it can always be replaced, and that is the mechanism by which one can insert text at the insertion point.

If you select that option, the AppleScript snippet above is the complete script. 
 It's not life-changing by any means, but it's less work for AppleScript, and it removes a dependency (no call outs to *System Events*), and, academically speaking, this infers benefits to speed, overhead, and stability.

With no need to use *System Events*, you now have the option of swapping out the AppleScript and using a single shell script:

[image: Automator Service Workflow in macOS (Shell script)]

Once again, a theoretical improvement.  Does any of this have any genuinely demonstrable/practical gains ?  Probably not.  But I think it's nice to have options.

Comment: Hi CJK, I'm genuinely interested to know more about: _"it incurs a lot of overhead and any performance from retrieving a date via a shell command are obliterated and negatively affected by the time it takes from AppleScript to create a shell process"_ - What is the overhead and negative affect?.. Do you have any ballpark performance related metrics relating to this? Are these moot micro-optimizations or is it genuinely a much bigger issue as implied ?

Comment: In the spirit of writing less code ... Since the `«class isot» as string` portion returns the e.g., `"2019-06-20T11:02:00"` format, then in your Run AppleScript solution, `":"` is not really needed as a `text item delimiters`. This is because it never comes into play, as you are only after `text items 1 thru 3`, which `"T"` provides the break point for the first three text items since `"-"` separated the components of the date string. (Sorry, I just couldn't resist.) That said, another excellent answer and needless to say +1!

Comment: Hi @RobC It’s second-hand information, I’m afraid, but the source was someone who used to be a software engineer at Apple so I was happy to take it at face value. That said, calls to `do shell script` in AppleScript are demonstrable in the time it takes to instantiate a shell process on a slow system, and scripts that make multiple calls compared to those that make a single call with a compound shell command can really drag. I think I will rephrase what I wrote as you’re right that it sounds alarmist. It’s a relative optimisation rather than absolute, but worth it if you have limited resources

Comment: @user3439894 Ha, with the amount I went on about optimisation, I deserve to be nitpicked. Point taken... But 10 points received too, thanks! The first draft made use of the colon delimiter because I went on to `tell` a record object to store each component as `{year:item 1, month:item 2, ..., hours:item 4, …}` and to return the relevant ones for reassembly thinking it would help others easily create timestamps. But then I thought of KISS, and cleaned up all the gaff, but missed a spot.  Next time, I’ll get it just right.

Comment: Hi @CJK - thanks for feedback. Interesting, the only reason I asked was because it contradicted the metrics we were getting In Automator's _log_. It was reporting greater duration time (from start to completion) when: **1)** Using a _"Run Shell Script"_ to obtain the date and passing it to a _"Run AppleScript"_. _vs_ **2)** Shelling out the `date` command in a single _"Run AppleScript"_. The times were approx  _0.170 secs_ for method **1** and _0.040 secs_ for method **2**.  Is the duration you get vice-versa, i.e does method 2 take longer ?

Comment: @RobC Let me get back to you and I’ll run it myself later.  That does surprise me, but, all else being equal, I would obviously trust the empirical data and employ for practical, everyday use.  If I get something similar, I’ll add a note to this effect in the answer, or do that strike-out effect to indicate that I have been disproven.

Comment: No worries @CJK, you really don't have to make edits on my behalf - we're splitting hairs over such a tiny delta ;) I believe the Apple engineers info was pertinent when we had slow processors and low RAM. I relate it to a similar idealistic view that was touted in the JS community for too long, which was, _"all methods must exist on the pseudo Classes prototype"_ - whilst this was a necessity years ago (multiple class's consumed precious RAM), however RAM nowadays is in abundance - thus somewhat negating the old-school arguments/justification.

Comment: @CJK, I figured the `":"` was there for a reason at one point and was then not used as you refined the code, but as I said... I just couldn't resist. BTW It was totally a joke and no intent to nitpick and just an observation I hoped we both get a laugh out of.

Comment: @user3439894 Oh, don't worry, I saw the humour in it.

Comment: @RobC I have to concede: running each version of the workflow 100 times took 131 seconds using two separate actions vs 97 seconds with a single AppleScript action shelling out the `date` command.  Just for fun, I also ran a third trial with a single shell action calling `osascript`, and this took 85 seconds.  The margins may not be as demonstrable as yours, but not insignificant either.  Thanks for calling me out on this.  I genuinely like having my mind changed.